# Where am I going wrong with localizattion?

Tags: iphone, localization

I have a plist file that contains numerous arrays, dictionaries, dictionaries that contain arrays of strings etc.

I perform the following steps:

1. clean poject
2. reset simulator
3. run app and all works fine
4. I add a Spanish localization to the plist file resulting in two identical plist files as I have not made any changes yet
5. clean project
6. reset simulator
7. run app and things go wrong!

For a start off the toolbar that gets its colour like this:

```
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.745f green:0.176f blue:0.306f alpha:1]];
```

is now black?

I also have three20 launcher view in place that now has no buttons visible?

Im at a loss as all I have done is create a localized version of the plist but as yet made no changes in it......so what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: you have "one" plist file? o_O
There should be a separate one for every localization.
And you don't use plists at all, but simple txt-files... like a folder "en.lproj" for english or "de.lproj" for german and they should contain a Localizable.strings file

Comment: no I have two, one in en.lproj and one in es.lproj, at present both identical

Comment: btw. if you're using Three20 anyway, you'll probably also have added the Three20.bundle... that one contains examples of how it should look... could be that yours and theirs are fighting each other

Comment: I was under the impression from what I have read you can use plist file as it is a resource and by localising such it creates a localized folder in this case es_lproj and places the plist file in it.  I do not understand how when the plist I am using has hundreds of entries at many levels that I can extract out just the ones I want to change a language for?

Answer (score 0):

You can localize plists, just found this link:

http://www.noorselijster19.com/2011/02/ios/localized-plist/

Using that example I replicated the structure in my plist and go a desired result.

So something is amis in the larger content of the plist file.....